# How do I add the data in a column Pandas

Tags: pandas

My  data looks like this:

```
Location    Price    Rooms  Bathrooms   
KLCC       1250000    2+1      3            
Dutamas    1030000     3       4         
Bukit Jali  900000    4+1      3
```

My question is for the column 'Rooms', how do I add the rows in the 'Rooms' column so that I can get the total room. It should looks like this:

```
Location    Price    Rooms  Bathrooms   
KLCC       1250000     3       3            
Dutamas    1030000     3       4         
Bukit Jali  900000     5       3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all columns from third position by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with [`eval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html):

```
df.iloc[:, 2:] = df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(pd.eval)
print (df)
     Location    Price Rooms Bathrooms
0        KLCC  1250000     3         3
1     Dutamas  1030000     3         4
2  Bukit Jali   900000     5         3
```

Alternative:

```
df.iloc[:, 2:] = df.iloc[:, 2:].applymap(pd.eval)
```